# Run javascript when anchor is clicked in the footer tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my footer html:

```
<footer>
    <div>
         <a href='a.aspx'>test 1</a>
         <a href='b.aspx'>test 2</a>
    </div>
    <a href='c.aspx'>test 3</a>
<footer>
```

Is there a way to always run a javascript function whenever a link is clicked within `<footer>` before it redirects? And is it possible to also find where it will redirect to within the function?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. `.querySelectorAll` is perfect selector for this.

```js
var footerAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("footer a");

footerAnchors.forEach(anchor => addClickListener(anchor));

function addClickListener(anchor){
  anchor.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    alert(event.target.href);
    event.preventDefault()
  })
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div>
         <a href='a.aspx'>test 1</a>
         <a href='b.aspx'>test 2</a>
    </div>
    <a href='c.aspx'>test 3</a>
<footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` for this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("footer a").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault() //use this to stop the default redirect if you want to do that manually
    const linkTarget = event.target.href
    console.log(linkTarget) //use this however you like

    if (linkTarget.includes("a.aspx"))
      document.location = linkTarget //for example redirecting if it contains a.aspx
  });
});
```

```html
<footer>
    <div>
         <a href='a.aspx'>test 1</a>
         <a href='b.aspx'>test 2</a>
    </div>
    <a href='c.aspx'>test 3</a>
<footer>
```

however, if you want to execute a function every time the site is left, not only by clicking a link, but also by clicking back in the browser for example, i suggest you use `window.onbeforeunload` for this, instead of event handlers in the footer: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to attach listeners to every anchor element.

Using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/438273) you can attach a single event listener to the footer element, and in the callback function check whether or not the clicked element was an anchor — then execute code related to each specific case.

[`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) can be used to check if the element that was clicked was an anchor, and then [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) can be used to prevent the default navigation behavior for the clicked anchor.

Here's a complete example:

```js
const footer = document.querySelector('footer');

function handleFooterClick (ev) {
  console.clear();

  // The click event was dispatched from an anchor element:
  if (ev.target.matches('a')) {
    // Prevent the default anchor navigation:
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('You would have navigated to:', ev.target.href);
  }
  else { // Not an anchor:
    console.log('You clicked another element:', ev.target.tagName);
  }
}

footer.addEventListener('click', handleFooterClick);
```

```html
<footer>
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <div>
    <a href='a.aspx'>test 1</a>
    <a href='b.aspx'>test 2</a>
  </div>
  <a href='c.aspx'>test 3</a>
</footer>
```